# Fetch update from backend or update redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Imagine a React app where you can list your friends in a sidebar. The site uses Redux to store the state of the friends. In case a user adds a new friend to his list, I have to send a POST to the backend, to save it.

The question is, how should I update the list of friends in the sidebar?

After the post, should I make a GET request and add the response to Redux or should I just use the data and add it directly to Redux, removing the extra GET call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion will be doing both. When you are making a request to server update the Redux store which will update your state(Friends list) and will rerender the component.
Also fire the GET request action, so that if there are data that are on the server but not in your redux, that should get retrieved.
(imagine: Using two machine at the same time and adding friends)

And if you are using something similar to a pure component, if your redux store and retrieved data are same, i.e., no new data was available on the server, there will be no change in state and component will not re-render. They will re-render only when there is a difference in state and will display the current list.

Answer (score 0):

IMO both options are valid. However, I like to have a single source of truth in our applications, which is the backend in most cases.

Sometimes, you might even choose to go for both options. This will increase the user experience by preventing a loading state, but if the action fails or the backend data is different than your redux store, it can result in "weird" behavior.